Abuse of Abuse reporting system / Feedback loop by spfbl.net
We are getting below abuse emails from Abuse reporting system / Feedback loop by spfbl.net
Can someone explain how are these even valid Abuse emails in any sense at all, because they are clearly being blocked at SMTP level itself (without an email being ever sent)?
Is their no guideline or RFC to state what or when and Abuse complaint should happen?

If you believe that this report is a mistake, request to recipient the release of this sender at https://matrix.spfbl.net/xxxxxxxxxx

If you have any question about this abuse, contact the mail box administrator [postmaster@xxxx.com.br].

For more information about this abuse format below, see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5965

Feedback-Type: abuse
User-Agent: SPFBL/3.1
Version: 1
Original-Mail-From: [xxxxx@xxxxx.com]
Original-Rcpt-To: [xxxxxx@xxxxx.com]
Arrival-Date: Tue, 04 Jun 2024 19:13:29 -0300
Reporting-MTA: dns; xxx.xxx.com.br
Source-IP: xx.xx.xx.xx
Authentication-Results: xxx.xxx.com.br; smtp.mail=xxxx@xxxx.com; spf=pass

This email message was rejected at RCPT TO command, so we don't have its headers.



If you are responsible for a server that attempts to relay messages where already at the RCPT TO stage the attempt can be determined as abusive, I would consider that more concerning than attempting to relay messages only later identified as abusive . Did you possibly configure an EHLO name that you are not authorized to use, or attempt to deliver messages to a destination address that was not meant to be shared with you?

@anx It looks like height of stupidity actually. Because data comes after RCPT TO, imagine that. https://www.wikihow.com/Send-Email-Using-Telnet and no PTR, Forward Record etc are properly configured. I mean if you want to block a recipient it's fine, but Abuse report, like what the heck.

I think this message itself is spam and is tricking you in openning the attachment (.dat file).
I recieved 4 of them, checked al MTA and Recipients in the outgoing mail log also the ip and hostname but never found a record that a message whas send there way.

I suspect the MUA you are viewing the message from is acting little funny about mime types such as text/rfc822-headers, message/rfc822, message/whatever. It is customary to send whatever headers the report was based on along with the human-readable note and the ARF-structured report. They should be readable in the plaintext of the report mail.

@barberos Actually the email is legit coming from spfbl.net and is being sent over as Abuse complaint to both IP owner as well as PTR owner's abuse email. But it really feels height of stupidity because there is no email sent at all, and it's not like their precious servers are being pinged non-stop.


Can someone explain how are these even valid Abuse emails in any sense
at all, because they are clearly being blocked at SMTP level itself
(without an email being ever sent)?

One can abuse message exchanges in ways beyond just the case of successfully dropping a load of unsolicited and/or otherwise fraudulent messages at their door. Examples include:

you use names (or have published names to addresses you use) that clearly do not identify you (You might be trying to impersonate someone else)
you try to deliver messages to an unusual share of non-existing addresses (You may be just guessing recipient names and checking which ones are valid. Spammers do that sometimes. You have no business in even trying.)
you pretend to have mail for existing addresses, then keep cancelling the delivery (Again something only spammers deliberately do. Never lie about having messages to deliver.)

If you do shady stuff, whether the concern with that is resource consumption or concerns in damaging the privacy or the effectiveness of spam filtering, people can and will complain about you. There is absolutely no rule that limits this particular mechanism of notifying about abusive behaviour in the context of email systems just to cases where messages have been transferred, or even have been confirmed as received.
